# Why Object#create must precede instantiation of child class

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a simple inheritance issue in JavaScript where a `Child` class inherits from a `Parent` class. However, in using Object#create to establish the inheritance, it seems that it must come before instantiation of the `Child` class:

```
function Child() {}

function Parent() {}

Parent.prototype.sayhello = function () {
    console.log("hello world");
}

// Apparently, this must precede instantiation:
// Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); //works, console logs "hello world"

var c = new Child();

// We get a TypeError: c.sayhello is not a function
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

c.sayhello(); //TypeError: c.sayhello is not a function
```

My thinking was that even if `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` came after the instantiation, we are still setting the `Child` class's prototype to point to the `Parent`'s prototype, so when `sayhello` is called, the prototypal chain is searched until the method is found. Why doesn't this work? I must be misunderstanding something fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `new Child()`, the returned object is linked (via `__proto__`) to the *current value* of `Child.prototype`.

When you assign a new object to `Child.prototype` after that, that does not affect the existing instance (which still points to the old prototype object).

Comment: I thought any new objects referenced the same constructor prototype. So can you say the objects reference "their own" copies of the prototype objects? Not sure what's a correct technical way of saying it

Comment: @fibono: You're confusing objects and references.  They reference the object that `.prototype` _currently points to_.

Comment: sorry, I'm still not 100% clear. So is there a "new" and an "old" prototype object in this case--two separate objects?

Comment: @fibono: Yes  – the original value of `Child.prototype` and the result of `Object.create(...)`.  You need to understand the difference between mutating an object and replacing it with a new object.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `var c = new Child()` you are constructing a new Child object. A prototype has not yet been declared for this constructor when the `c` object is made, so its prototype is undefined and remains undefined. It does not update when you declare prototype properties of the Constructor after the fact. That `c` object remains frozen with regard to its prototype as it has already been made.

Remember that Javascript is pseudoclassical. Everything is an object, there are no real classes.

Comment: Why doesn't it update though? I thought that `c`'s `_proto_` points to `Child.prototype`, so when `Child.prototype` is updated (even if after the fact) to point to `Parent.prototype`, then `c``s`_proto_` points to that updated `Child.prototype` object.

Comment: @fibono: You aren't "updating the `Child.prototype` object"  – you're making an entirely new object and setting `.prototype` to point to it.